# Issue regarding printing of mysql query result in ejs page

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have written my code in node.js to retrieve result from mysql database.

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.get_js_value);
    var items = req.body.get_js_value.split(',');
    var sql ="SELECT rname FROM recipes WHERE ringre LIKE '%" +items[0]+"%' ";
    for( var i=1;i<items.length;i++){
        sql = sql + "AND ringre LIKE '%"+items[+i]+"%' ";
    }console.log(sql);
    con.query(sql, function(err,result){
        if(err){throw err;}
        else{
            console.log(result);
            res.render("recipes_response", { recipes: result });
        }
    });
 });
app.listen(port, () => console.log("example app listening on port %s",port));

and ejs code is:
<html>
    <head>
        <title>recipes</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Recipes are</h2>
        <div>
            <%= recipes %>
        </div>                         
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I am running this code am getting the o/p like
Recipes are
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] 
in my webpage

I need my result to get printed as names of my recipes.
Will you guys help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the answer by modifying my code in js file by adding the below line after console.log(result):

```
var result = JSON.stringify(result);
```

Then I just got my answer as I needed.